# subclass_from_attributes works fine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.2, sti

I have several classes inherited with STI with the replacing of `inheritance_column` in a kind of classy way:

```
module A
class Base < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.inheritance_column = 'provider'

  PROVIDERS = {
    'a_b' => 'B',
    'a_c' => 'C'
  }

  # STI helpers
  def self.find_sti_class(type_name)
    "A::#{PROVIDERS[type_name]}".constantize or super(type_name)
  end

  def self.sti_name
    PROVIDERS.invert[name.split("::")[-1]]
  end
  # end STI helpers

end # class Base
end # module A 


# b.rb

module A
  class B < A; end
end

# c.rb

module A
  class C < A; end
end
```

The whole thing works fine for existing objects, but problems begin when I try to create a new object:

```
A::Base.new(provider: 'a_b')
```

gives me

```
ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound: Invalid single-table inheritance type: a_b is not a subclass of A::Base
from /bundler_cache/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:215:in `subclass_from_attributes'
    from /bundler_cache/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:55:in `new'
    from (irb):16
    from /bundler_cache/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /bundler_cache/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /bundler_cache/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /bundler_cache/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /bundler_cache/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

It could be clearly seen, that no `find_sti_class` is called on a `new` call. I've also inserted some debug output in my `self.find_sti_class` and it wasn't called.

OK, use the source, Luke.
Go to [apidock](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Inheritance/ClassMethods/subclass_from_attributes) and see:

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb, line 208
      def subclass_from_attributes(attrs)
        subclass_name = attrs.with_indifferent_access[inheritance_column]

        if subclass_name.present? && subclass_name != self.name
          subclass = subclass_name.safe_constantize

          unless descendants.include?(subclass)
            raise ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound.new("Invalid single-table inheritance type: #{subclass_name} is not a subclass of #{name}")
          end

          subclass
        end
      end
```

So, does not matter whether we redefined our `sti_name` or not, it still wants the value from `attributes[inheritance_column]` to match the class name!

It seems to be fixed in Rails 5 (as I can see on github): it calls  `find_sti_class`, and should work fine.

But in rails 4.2 it still seems confusing.

Am I misreading something, or is it true, that in that case, the only way I can create an object of an inherited class is to create it by directly calling `#new` from this class like this:
`A::B.new`?

Answer (score 0):

You could do...

```
def self.new(options={})
  options[:provider] = find_sti_class(options[:provider]) if options[:provider]
  super(options)
end
```

Comment: So, it is a known bug and anyone knows about it? I found nothing about this (may be searched badly), but I couldn't be the first one, who tries to do this

Comment: Also, this solution would create objects with the class name, e.g. `A::B` in `provider` column instead of expected `a_b`